# Is is better to store serialized data or raw html in mysql?

Tags: php, serialization, caching

I de-normalized my database, since the application was crawling otherwise, and Im storing a list of categories for each item in the DB as a raw html version, and simply echoing it out in my design. Each category is actually a link, which is include a  tag. Naturally, this is  abit of a pain, especially if I want to change the look of how the category links are displayed, since I gotta update all the old cached entries.

What if I were to store this data as a serialized array instead, and simply unserialize it, and then apply formatting to it in php. Would there be a significant performance decrease over simply echoing out the raw html?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to store values serialized only for a specific language in a database.

Did you consider [memcache](http://memcached.org/) to reduce "crawls" of your database? I usually find caching to be a much more elegant and flexible solution than a de-normaliezd database.

Comment: Already use memcache, except there are 2 million objects, which need to be recached several times a day, so the BUILDING of the cache should be optimized.

Comment: Two million objects each have their own HTML list of categories? I suppose you'll need to share more details about your application if you want an answer more detailed than "no, don't store serialized PHP objects in a database."

Comment: Its a movie listing application. I need to show movie genres + actors associated with each movie, which all have to be clickable links. I store the movie-actor, movie-genre, movie-director ID pairs in relational tables, but when there are 1.5 million movies, and each movie has an average of 15 actors, that creates a very large lookup table, that it would need to query on every cache build. thats why I store the actual lists as raw html in a special column of every item in the DB.

Comment: why can't you just pull ids for each item and build the HTML around the "display" value using PHP? href="get.php?type=actor&id=123">Johnny Depp</a> ?

Comment: Those sound like very fast queries if properly indexed. You shouldn't need to cache HTML in the database.

Comment: If your site grows to the point where your database becomes a bottleneck, lazily cache the entire page in memcache. Presumably only a small subset of movies receive multiple hits per hour, and those are the only pages that would benefit from caching.